# Programatically generating contour map in Unity 3d over a flat surface

Tags: unity-game-engine, contour

I am working on a project in Unity3D in which I have to Generate a contour map from data obtained from formulas separately over a flat surface.

I have a simple  2d surface rotated in 3d. Imagine a surface such as this:

```
. . . 
. . . 
. . .
```

I want to generate (not just apply texture of a) contour on this surface on the basis of temperature data at different points on it. This not permanent and recalculation of data will show new contours.
Data of temperature will be mathematically created from formulas like this:

```
34 54 79
56 80 108
89 110 120
```

Is there any way to do this?

I am looking for possible technique and code that may help but any help in getting the desired result would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D%3a_Noob_to_Pro/Landscape_Modeling_III%3a_Exporting_as_a_Heightmap) about how to create a [heightmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heightmap) of your model. From there, you have the contours found, you only need to include the texture and draw the lines. Since heightmaps are grayscale, it is easy to find the contours (or create a topographic map), if you use an approach similar to the one found [here](http://www.onformative.com/lab/creating-contour-maps/). You need only apply contours onto the texture, and you have your contour map.

Just to overview

1. Create a heightmap
2. Create a script to find the contours (probably using blob detection)
3. Apply the contoured image (probably a binary image) onto the texture so the topographic lines are visible

Comment: The answer you provided was correct for the previous version of my question. Now I have corrected my question.

Comment: I want  to generate the contour on the surface instead of creating it by hand. There is no need to find the contours or detect them because it will be created separately using formulas.

Comment: I need something like this http://www.silvaco.com.cn/products/tcad/Stress_Simulator/i/vic_stress_fig3b.jpg

Yes, I already have the values of temperatures (heightmap).

Comment: @atetree So you want the surface to be colored by the tempuratures?

Comment: Yes. In such a way that when the variables are changed, the contours shown on the object are also changed/redrawn.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do it :P